# How to use @googlemaps/js-api-loader asynchronously in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

```
  const loadGoogleInstance = async () => {
    try {
      const google = new Loader({
        apiKey: "sdfsd", //passing an invalid key to test error handling
        version: "weekly",
        libraries: [],
        region: "GR",
      });

      await google.load();

      setGoogleInstance(google);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Google Maps API failed to load", error);
      alert("Google Maps API failed to load");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated) loadGoogleInstance();
    return () => {
      setGoogleInstance(null);
    };
  }, [isAuthenticated]);
```

Is'nt this supposed to return an error promise when it fails to load due to an invalid apikey ?
Nothing gets caught in the catch block but instead i get a warning log :

`Google Maps JavaScript API warning: InvalidKey https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#invalid-key`

Comment: Hello. It could be because any subsequent code gets ignored when an error is encountered or it pushes through the try part and never gets to the catch, but still the API is just returning the error as a response of not having a valid API key. But why would you still want to do this though if the API is already returning a very useful error?

Comment: @Yrll
Thanks for your message, i'm not sure where to expect this error and take action on it, since google.load() does not return a rejected promise
, i can listen to console.warn and show an alert from there, but it seems relatively hacky

Comment: Have you seen this JS question? Do you think this would still apply to your React use case?